# Detect if 32 or 64 bit windows and define var

Tags: wix

I want to install Visual C++ 2012 redistribute with my app. I would like to install the appropriate version based on the architecture of the machine. eg

```
if platfrom is x86
    vcredist_filename = Microsoft_VC120_CRT_x86.ms
else
    vcredist_filename = Microsoft_VC120_CRT_x64.ms
```

Ive tried to accomplish in many differents ways but I cant get it working. What ive tried:

```
    <?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
        <?define VC120Redist_FileName="Microsoft_VC120_CRT_x64.msm" ?>
    <?else ?>
        <?define VC120Redist_FileName="Microsoft_VC120_CRT_x86.msm" ?>
    <?endif ?>

    (undefined preprocesss variable "Platform").

    <?if $(var.VersionNT64) ?>
        <?define VC120Redist_FileName="Microsoft_VC120_CRT_x64.msm" ?>
    <?else ?>
        <?define VC120Redist_FileName="Microsoft_VC120_CRT_x8.msm" ?>
    <?endif ?>

     (undefined preprocesss variable "VersionNT64").

    <?if ![CDATA[VersionNT64]] ?>
        <?define VC120Redist_FileName="Microsoft_VC120_CRT_x64.msm" ?>
    <?endif?>

     (unexpected literal ![CDATA[VersionNT64]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use two separate components with conditions like this:

```
<Component Id="Foo" Guid="{GUID}" Win64="yes"> 
  <Condition>
    <![CDATA[VersionNT64 OR $(var.Platform) = "x64"]]>
  </Condition>
</Component>

<Component Id="Bar" Guid="{GUID}">
  <Condition>
    <![CDATA[NOT(VersionNT64) OR $(var.Platform) = "x86"]]>
  </Condition>
</Component>
```